# Parse JSON with single, double quotes and unicode with python 2.7

Tags: python, json

TL:DR: I'm trying to pass with curl a JSON content and getting failed.

I have a file with the following content:

test_api.txt content:

```
data={"crt":"t45","res_type":1,"stype":"standard","config":"{u'global': {u'lang': [], u'floor': u'1', u'tmax': 1000, u'dsp': [{u'status': u'disable', u'id': u'92'}], u'request_at': 3, u'crt_list': [{u'width': u'25', u'height': u'50', u'stype': u'restype', u'format': u'restype'}], u'request': True, u'geo': [{u'geo_id': u'21', u'floor': u'50'}]}}","sl_org":555,"parse_to":1111,"group_id":2020,"name":"test_api"}
```

The value of data is valid json, as far as I understand, because all online validators are agree that it's valid. And actually this is a result of python's `json.dumps()`.

And I'm sending it this way:

```
curl -v -X POST 'https://example.com/api/v2/entity/create' -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d  "@test_api.txt"
```

What I see if i print POST conent:

```
<QueryDict: {u'data': [u'{"crt":"t45","res_type":1,"stype":"standard","config":"{u\'global\': {u\'lang\': [], u\'floor\': u\'1\', u\'tmax\': 1000, u\'dsp\': [{u\'status\': u\'disable\', u\'id\': u\'92\'}], u\'request_at\': 3, u\'crt_list\': [{u\'width\': u\'25\', u\'height\': u\'50\', u\'stype\': u\'restype\', u\'format\': u\'restype\'}], u\'request\': True, u\'geo\': [{u\'geo_id\': u\'21\', u\'floor\': u\'50\'}]}}","sl_org":555,"parse_to":1111,"group_id":2020,"name":"test_api"}']}>
```

Next I parse that code with json.loads() anf I get the following dict:

```
{u'stype': u'standard', u'config': u"{u'global': {u'lang': [], u'floor': u'1', u'tmax': 1000, u'dsp': [{u'status': u'disable', u'id': u'92'}], u'request_at': 3, u'crt_list': [{u'width': u'25', u'height': u'50', u'stype': u'restype', u'format': u'restype'}], u'request': True, u'geo': [{u'geo_id': u'21', u'floor': u'50'}]}}", u'name': u'test_api', u'parse_to': 1111, u'res_type': 1, u'crt': u't45', u'sl_org': 555, u'group_id': 2020}
```

And now I have to parse the value of 'config' key in this dict, that actually contents a string with another JSON-field:

```
value = u"{u'global': {u'lang': [], u'floor': u'1', u'tmax': 1000, u'dsp': [{u'status': u'disable', u'id': u'92'}], u'request_at': 3, u'crt_list': [{u'width': u'25', u'height': u'50', u'stype': u'restype', u'format': u'restype'}], u'request': True, u'geo': [{u'geo_id': u'21', u'floor': u'50'}]}}"
```

And here is the problem: any try to parse this string with json with `json.loads(value)` is going to be failed:

`"ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)"`

Yes, it has single quotes inside of double quotes and it doesn't look right but I'm getting this string with default `json.loads()`, as you can see, so that what python does.

And my question is - what is going wrong and how to fix it? I'm passing valid json through standard symmetric python functions and getting broken json a result. How can I fix this pipeline and get this json parse correctly?

Comment: Your inner content *isn't JSON*. `{u'global': ...}` is a Python serialization, not a JSON one.

Comment: You can parse that with `ast.literal_eval()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer structure is JSON, but the inner content is not JSON but a Python literal; thus, you need to use Python-syntax-aware tools, not JSON tools, for it.

```
import json, ast

json_str = '''{"crt":"t45","res_type":1,"stype":"standard","config":"{u'global': {u'lang': [], u'floor': u'1', u'tmax': 1000, u'dsp': [{u'status': u'disable', u'id': u'92'}], u'request_at': 3, u'crt_list': [{u'width': u'25', u'height': u'50', u'stype': u'restype', u'format': u'restype'}], u'request': True, u'geo': [{u'geo_id': u'21', u'floor': u'50'}]}}","sl_org":555,"parse_to":1111,"group_id":2020,"name":"test_api"}'''
data = json.loads(json_str)
config = ast.literal_eval(data['config'])

print(config['global']['tmax']) # emits 1000
```

Comment: Hmm, I was pretty sure that inner 'json' is a result of json.dumps(value), it's an actually a form field was dumped. Let me check it, please.

Comment: It looks like you are right, it' just a string. Thanks a lot!